# Insert/Update MySQL into longtext Column

Tags: mysql

How do I insert the following string into MySQL:

```
$myValue ouputs: [Hey, this is a multi text file that has special characters like this ' and this '' and this ,,"", and this ''' and this '''' and this !@$ and whatever]
```

But the following will not work because of special characters:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `mytable` SET NEWS=('$myValue') WHERE _id='1'";
```

I do not want to manually escape every character (like adding an ' before every ')

Update/Insert should should start at [ and end at ] (as seen in $myValue)

EDIT (mysqli)

```
    $_myValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($myValue);

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE `mytable` SET NEWS='$_myValue' WHERE _id='1'";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }
```

Comment: what language are you using to generate the output/push to db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the syntax of your code I assume that php is used to submit the queries to mysql.

If you just want to escape special characters in a string variable passed to a field, then use

- [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) (if you use PDO)
- [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (if you use mysqli)
- [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (if you use mysql, although you should  not)

If you are looking for a more generic solution gainst sql injection, then consider using prepared statements. See [this landmark SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) on how to prevent SQL injection in php-mysql environment.

Comment: I edited my question with modification, I'm using mysqli however the escape_string $_myValue is returning '' (nothing) while $myValue is returning data before conversion.

Comment: ok, i included the connection,escapestring.. let me see how that works out, ill provide feedback

Answer (score 0):

If your using php you could look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php);

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

$sql = "UPDATE `mytable` SET NEWS=:myValue WHERE _id=1";
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue(":myValue", $myValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
```

This will input all the data stored in `$myValue`. I would look at sanatising the input too.